# Is there any detailed description of Virat(universal) form of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu

We all knows Vishnu has Virat or Universal form. I came accross with some explanation of Virat Swaroop of Vishnu in Ramayan, When
Mandodari was trying to convince Ravana about not to make Rama his enemy, then She told about Rama that He is Vishnu himself. He is supreme Lord himself. Patal is feets of him and Swarg (or may said other loka) is head, Clouds are hairs of him, Shiva is ego of him. Don't remember exact description right now. But Mandodari covers whole
universe as body parts of Vishnu. I don't know if Mandodari's explanation towards Vishnu's universal form was true Or it was just to make Ravana scare so that he gave up on Sita and don't make Rama as enemy.

So is there any description about this universal form of Vishnu in detail i.e. in any Vedas/puranas or in any other Hindu sources? There must be someone who has described Vishnu's universal form in detail in any Puranas or Vedas.

Comment: @sinister I am not asking Virat swaroop from Mahabharata. Did I mentioned anywhere Mahabharat in my question. Perspective of Mahabharata is different. I am asking about Virat swaroop not according to Mahabharat. Read question carefully before flagging. There are many other puranas in which virat swaroop described differently. And one example has shown by @ SwiftPushkar in his answer. I am repeating myself that my question is not limited to one purana only!!

Comment: Don't let the title fool you.  See the linked question and read it's body "so I wanted to know how this looked as per the Mahabharata or the Bhagavad Gita or *wherever it is described.*" Read the question carefully.

Comment: Don't feel bad or feel thatI'm always after you. I was searching some old questions and found this question. Your question is also good. Getting a duplicate tag is not a bad thing but they're discouraged when the questions are too popular. Some Q's don't get easily :D.  Please don't delete your questions once it gets a duplicate tag. They are helpful for other users . There are a few [dupe questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5212+closed%3A1) of mine too.

Comment: @Sinister I am not feeling bad, thanks for your concern :) I know the original question should grab visiters more than duplicate one. This is the reason I accepted it as duplicate so that in future if some came in my post then they can read more about Virat form in original post also. Thus like this they will have more detail to read about Virat form of Vishnu. It's good original question has linked with mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes** there is detail description about this universal form of Vishnu in [**Shreemad Bhagvat purana**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/1) – Second Chapter  Verse 24-39  : SB 2.1: The First Step in God Realization. **Here we can see the description of the gigantic universal form of the Lord Vishnu.** **i.e. Virat Swaroopa ,similar to Purusha-Sukta .**

Note that the exact Purausha-Sukta   Is also there in Shreemad Bhagvat purana apart from this and that is the description of Virat Purusha  we find in Vedas  and Upanishads.

> अण्डकोशे शरीरेऽस्मिन्सप्तावरणसंयुते ।
>  वैराजः पुरुषो योऽसौ
>   भगवान्धारणाश्रयः ॥25॥ 
>  aṇḍa-kośe śarīre 'smin
>   saptāvaraṇa-saḿyute vairājaḥ puruṣo yo 'sau bhagavān
>   dhāraṇāśrayaḥ
>
> **The gigantic universal form of the Personality of Godhead, within the body of the universal shell,** which is covered by sevenfold
>   material elements, is the subject for the viraṭ conception.[**SB
>   2.1.25**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/1/25)
>
> ---
>
> द्वे जानुनी सुतलं विश्वमूर्तेरूरुद्वयं वितलं चातलं च ।
>  महीतलं तज्जघनं महीपते नभस्तलं नाभिसरो गृणन्ति ॥27॥
>
> dve jānunī sutalaḿ viśva-mūrter ūru-dvayaḿ vitalaḿ cātalaḿ ca
>   mahītalaḿ taj-jaghanaḿ mahīpate nabhastalaḿ nābhi-saro
>   gṛṇanti
>
> The knees of the universal form are the planetary system of the name
>   Sutala, and the two thighs are the Vitala and Atala planetary systems.
>   The hips are Mahitala, and outer space is the depression of His
>   navel.[**SB 2.1.27**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/1/27)
>
> ---
>
> द्यौरक्षिणी चक्षुरभूत्पतङ्गः पक्ष्माणि
>   विष्णोरहनी उभे च । 
>  तद्भ्रूविजृम्भः परमेष्ठिधिष्ण्यमापोऽस्य तालू
>   रस एव जिह्वा ॥30॥
>
> dyaur akṣiṇī cakṣur abhūt patańgaḥ pakṣmāṇi viṣṇor ahanī ubhe
>   ca
>  tad-bhrū-vijṛmbhaḥ parameṣṭhi-dhiṣṇyam āpo 'sya tālū rasa
>   eva jihvā
>
> The sphere of outer space constitutes His eyepits, and the eyeball is
>   the sun as the power of seeing. His eyelids are both the day and
>   night, and in the movements of His eyebrows, Brahma and similar
>   supreme personalities reside. His palate is the director of water,
>   Varuna, and the juice or essence of everything is His tongue.[**SB
>   2.1.30**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/1/30)
>
> ---
>
> नाड्योऽस्य नद्योऽथ तनूरुहाणि महीरुहा विश्वतनोर्नृपेन्द्र ।
>  अनन्तवीर्यः श्वसितं मातरिश्वा गतिर्वयः कर्म
>   गुणप्रवाहः ॥33॥
>
> nadyo 'sya nāḍyo 'tha tanū-ruhāṇi mahī-ruhā viśva-tanor
>   nṛpendra
>  ananta-vīryaḥ śvasitaḿ mātariśvā gatir vayaḥ karma
>   guṇa-pravāhaḥ
>
> O King, the rivers are the veins of the gigantic body, the trees are
>   the hairs of His body, and the omnipotent air is His breath. The
>   passing ages are His movements, and His activities are the reactions
>   of the three modes of material nature.[**SB 2.1.33**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/1/33)
>
> ---
>
> ब्रह्माननं क्षत्रभुजो महात्मा विडूरुरङ्घ्रिश्रितकृष्णवर्णः ।
>   नानाभिधाभीज्यगणोपपन्नो द्रव्यात्मकः कर्म वितानयोगः ॥37॥
>
> brahmānanaḿ kṣatra-bhujo mahatma viḍ ūrur
>   ańghri-śrita-kṛṣṇa-varṇaḥ nānābhidhābhījya-gaṇopapanno
>   dravyātmakaḥ karma vitāna-yogaḥ
>
> The viraṭ-purusa’s face is the brahmanas, His arms are the ksatriyas,
>   His thighs are the vaisyas, and the sudras are under the protection of
>   His feet. All the worshipable [**SB2.1.37**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/1/37)
>
> ---
>
> इयानसावीश्वरविग्रहस्य यः सन्निवेशः कथितो मया ते । 
>   सन्धार्यतेऽस्मिन्वपुषि स्थविष्ठे मनः स्वबुद्ध्या न यतोऽस्ति किञ्चित्
>   ॥38॥
>
> iyān asāv īśvara-vigrahasya yaḥ sanniveśaḥ kathito mayā te
>   sandhāryate 'smin vapuṣi sthaviṣṭhe manaḥ sva-buddhyā na yato 'sti
>   kiñcit
>
> **I have thus explained to you the gross material gigantic conception of the Personality of Godhead.** One who seriously desires liberation
>   concentrates his mind on this form of the Lord, because there is
>   nothing more than this in the material world.[**SB 2.1.38**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/1/38)

Comment: Great explanation +1, But there must also be some relevance with Shiva and other Lords also, not only materialistic. For example I heard earlier, Shiva is also part of him, people gets life from his mouth and after death goes in his mouth. The virat savarup that I have seen in Ramanad Sagar's Shree Krishna, in that People was coming from his mouth as baby and going in his mouth at old age. Is there any explanation of his universal form related to life and death process of nature?

Comment: @Rishabh - Thanks."Is there any explanation of his universal form related to life and death process of nature?" yes , i will search about this and will update you if found. :)

Answer (score 5):

Another description of Lord Vishnu Universal Form (Viraata Swaroopa) is given in [Bhagavada Gita, Chapter 11](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=11). Arjuna asked Lord Krishna to show his universal form, then Lord Krishna gave him divine eyes so that Arjuna can see his Universal form. Arjuna saw whole universe within Him, everything dissolving in Him. That form was so fierce that Arjuna trembled with fear.

I am providing the English Translation By Swami Sivananda.

> अर्जुन उवाच
>   पश्यामि देवांस्तव देव देहे
>   सर्वांस्तथा भूतविशेषसङ्घान्।
>   ब्रह्माणमीशं कमलासनस्थ
>   मृषींश्च सर्वानुरगांश्च दिव्यान्।।11.15।।
>
> 11.15 Arjuna said I see all the gods, O God, in Thy body, and (also) hosts of various classes of beings, Brahma, the Lord, seated on the lotus, all the sages and the celestial serpents.
>
> अनेकबाहूदरवक्त्रनेत्रं
>   पश्यामि त्वां सर्वतोऽनन्तरूपम्।
>   नान्तं न मध्यं न पुनस्तवादिं
>   पश्यामि विश्वेश्वर विश्वरूप।।11.16।।
>
> 11.16 I see Thee of boundless form on every side with many arms, stomachs, mouths and eyes: neither the end nor the middle nor also the beginning do I see, O Lord of the universe, O Cosmic Form.
>
> किरीटिनं गदिनं चक्रिणं च
>   तेजोराशिं सर्वतोदीप्तिमन्तम्।
>   पश्यामि त्वां दुर्निरीक्ष्यं समन्ता
>   द्दीप्तानलार्कद्युतिमप्रमेयम्।।11.17।।
>
> 11.17 I see Thee with the diadem, the club and the discus, a mass of radiance shining everywhere, very hard to look at, blazing all round like burning fire and the sun, and immeasurable.
>
> त्वमक्षरं परमं वेदितव्यं
>   त्वमस्य विश्वस्य परं निधानम्।
>   त्वमव्ययः शाश्वतधर्मगोप्ता
>   सनातनस्त्वं पुरुषो मतो मे।।11.18।।
>
> 11.18 Thou art the Imperishable, the Supreme Being, worthy to be known. Thou art the great treasure-house of this universe; Thou art the imperishable protector of the eternal Dhrama; Thou art the Primal Person, I deem.
>
> अनादिमध्यान्तमनन्तवीर्य
>   मनन्तबाहुं शशिसूर्यनेत्रम्।
>   पश्यामि त्वां दीप्तहुताशवक्त्रम्
>   स्वतेजसा विश्वमिदं तपन्तम्।।11.19।।
>
> 11.19 I see Thee without beginning, middle or end, infinite in power, of endless arms, the sun and the moon being Thy eyes, the burning fire Thy mouth, heating the whole universe with Thy radiance.
>
> द्यावापृथिव्योरिदमन्तरं हि
>   व्याप्तं त्वयैकेन दिशश्च सर्वाः।
>   दृष्ट्वाऽद्भुतं रूपमुग्रं तवेदं
>   लोकत्रयं प्रव्यथितं महात्मन्।।11.20।।
>
> 11.20 This space between the earth and the heaven and all the arters are filled by Thee alone; having seen this, Thy wonderful and teriible form, the three worlds are trembling with fear, O great-souled Being.
>
> अमी हि त्वां सुरसङ्घाः विशन्ति
>   केचिद्भीताः प्राञ्जलयो गृणन्ति।
>   स्वस्तीत्युक्त्वा महर्षिसिद्धसङ्घाः
>   स्तुवन्ति त्वां स्तुतिभिः पुष्कलाभिः।।11.21।।
>
> 11.21 Verily, into Thee enter these hosts of gods; some extol Thee in fear with joined palms; saying 'may it be well', bands of great sages and perfected ones praise Thee with hymns complete.
>
> रुद्रादित्या वसवो ये च साध्या
>   विश्वेऽश्िवनौ मरुतश्चोष्मपाश्च।
>   गन्धर्वयक्षासुरसिद्धसङ्घा
>   वीक्षन्ते त्वां विस्मिताश्चैव सर्वे।।11.22।।
>
> 11.22 The Rudras, Adityas, Vasus, Sadhyas, Visvedevas, the two Asvins, Maruts, the manes and the hosts of celestial singers, Yakshas, demons and the perfected ones, are all looking at Thee, in great amazement.
>
> रूपं महत्ते बहुवक्त्रनेत्रं
>   महाबाहो बहुबाहूरुपादम्।
>   बहूदरं बहुदंष्ट्राकरालं
>   दृष्ट्वा लोकाः प्रव्यथितास्तथाऽहम्।।11.23।।
>
> 11.23 Having seen Thy immeasurable form with many mouths and eyes, O mighty-armed, with many arms, thighs and feet, with many stomachs and fearful with many teeth the worlds are terrified and so am I.
>
> नभःस्पृशं दीप्तमनेकवर्णं
>   व्यात्ताननं दीप्तविशालनेत्रम्।
>   दृष्ट्वा हि त्वां प्रव्यथितान्तरात्मा
>   धृतिं न विन्दामि शमं च विष्णो।।11.24।।
>
> 11.24 On seeing Thee (the Cosmic Form) touching the sky, shining in many colours, with mouths wide open, with large fiery eyes, I am terrified at heart and find neither courage nor peace, O Vishnu.
>
> दंष्ट्राकरालानि च ते मुखानि
>   दृष्ट्वैव कालानलसन्निभानि।
>   दिशो न जाने न लभे च शर्म
>   प्रसीद देवेश जगन्निवास।।11.25।।
>
> 11.25 Having seen Thy mouths fearful with teeth (blazing) like the fires of cosmic dissolution, I know not the four arters, nor do I find peace. Have mercy, O Lord of the gods, O abode of the universe.
>
> अमी च त्वां धृतराष्ट्रस्य पुत्राः
>   सर्वे सहैवावनिपालसङ्घैः।
>   भीष्मो द्रोणः सूतपुत्रस्तथाऽसौ
>   सहास्मदीयैरपि योधमुख्यैः।।11.26।।
>
> 11.26 All the sons of Dhritarashtra, with the hosts of kings of the earth, Bhishma, Drona and Karna, with the chief among our warriors.
>
> वक्त्राणि ते त्वरमाणा विशन्ति
>   दंष्ट्राकरालानि भयानकानि।
>   केचिद्विलग्ना दशनान्तरेषु
>   संदृश्यन्ते चूर्णितैरुत्तमाङ्गैः।।11.27।।
>
> 11.27 Some hurriedly enter Thy mouths with their terrible teeth, fearful to behold. Some are found sticking in the gaps between the teeth with their heads crushed to powder.
>
> यथा नदीनां बहवोऽम्बुवेगाः
>   समुद्रमेवाभिमुखाः द्रवन्ति।
>   तथा तवामी नरलोकवीरा
>   विशन्ति वक्त्राण्यभिविज्वलन्ति।।11.28।।
>
> 11.28 Verily, just as many torrents of rivers flow towards the ocean, even so these heroes in the world of men enter Thy flaming mouths.
>
> यथा प्रदीप्तं ज्वलनं पतङ्गा
>   विशन्ति नाशाय समृद्धवेगाः।
>   तथैव नाशाय विशन्ति लोका
>   स्तवापि वक्त्राणि समृद्धवेगाः।।11.29।।
>
> 11.29 As moths hurriedly rush into a blazing fire for (their own) destruction, so also these creatures hurriedly rush into Thy mouths for (their own) destruction.
>
> लेलिह्यसे ग्रसमानः समन्ता
>   ल्लोकान्समग्रान्वदनैर्ज्वलद्भिः।
>   तेजोभिरापूर्य जगत्समग्रं
>   भासस्तवोग्राः प्रतपन्ति विष्णो।।11.30।।
>
> 11.30 Thou lickest up, devouring all the worlds on every side with Thy flaming mouths. Thy fierce rays, filling the whole world with radiance, are burning, O Vishnu!
>
> आख्याहि मे को भवानुग्ररूपो
>   नमोऽस्तु ते देववर प्रसीद।
>   विज्ञातुमिच्छामि भवन्तमाद्यं
>   न हि प्रजानामि तव प्रवृत्तिम्।।11.31।।
>
> 11.31 Tell me, who Thou art, so fierce of form. Salutations to Thee, O God Supreme: have mercy. I desire to know Thee, the original Being. I know not indeed Thy working.
>
> श्री भगवानुवाच
>   कालोऽस्मि लोकक्षयकृत्प्रवृद्धो
>   लोकान्समाहर्तुमिह प्रवृत्तः।
>   ऋतेऽपि त्वां न भविष्यन्ति सर्वे
>   येऽवस्थिताः प्रत्यनीकेषु योधाः।।11.32।।
>
> 11.32 The Blessed Lord said I am the full-grown world-destroying Time, now engaged in destroying the worlds. Even without thee, none of the warriors arrayed in the hostile armies shall live.